# Change line icon color on WordPress

Tags: css, icons

I need to change the color of these icons for my WordPress site and make them black.

How do I do that using CSS code to add at the customize theme options?

Thanks!

[Line icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73qDn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact the image you are linking to has a white background this would have to be changed on the image itself if you want true black - or the image would need a transparent background, then you could do a filter:brightness(0) to the image. If you don't want to change that and are ok with a gray icon you could add a filter to the image for grayscale - filter:grayscale(1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I noticed the icon stays like this with hover, and I'd like to make this fixed, permanent with a background color, instead of the hover. How do I do that? I'm a newbie with this. https://ibb.co/PMG9vtH

Comment: Do you have your code where you applied the CSS? It sounds like you have it on a Psuedo class :hover

Comment: I don't have any code for this, but I thought of adding this code at Appearance/Customize/Additional CSS

Comment: Do you have a site with the icons to look at? What I would recommend for flexibility is to have the image have a transparent background and apply a background color to image or the container of the image in the CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the transparency idea, but I think I don't have access to those icons. I was thinking about using Font Awesome icons.

Comment: I would recommend fontawesome - I use the icons regularly, and these should have a transparent background that would let you do what you want.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!